# how can i make this function return the table displaying the array data

Tags: php

I created a function accepting an array of data
and I want to return this HMTL by creating a table with already displayed date
But the foreach does not display the HTML and not of any error.

My question is: how can I make this function return the table displaying the array data ??

My Function:

```
<?php

function GetTableResult($arrayData) {

  return "<table id='Grid' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer DTTT_selectable' role='grid' aria-describedby='dynamic-table_info'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Date</th>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Name</th>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Procedure</th>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Provider Name</th>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Bravery</th>                                         
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Coparticipation</th>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Type</th>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Date Reference`enter code here`</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>";
            foreach($arrayData as $data){
             "<tr id='Grid_Linha_1' class='odd' role='row'>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['date']             . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['name']             . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['procedure']        . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['provider_name']   . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['bravery']          . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['coparticipation'  . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['type']             . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['date_reference']  . "</td>
            </tr>";
            }
          "</tbody>
        </table>";
}
```

Comment: If you `return` something, it has to go somewhere. For example: `$myArray = array(); $result = GetTableResult($myArray);` Now the output of your function will be returned to the variable `$result`. Afther that you can `echo $result;` for example.

Comment: You're missing a bracket after coparticipation and try to echo instead of returning the values. It should solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified example, but you should get the gist:

```
<?php

function GetTableResult($arrayData) {
    $table = '<table>';

    foreach($arrayData as $data) {
        $table .= "<tr id='Grid_Linha_1' class='odd' role='row'>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>${data['date']}</td>
              ...
            </tr>";
    }
    $table .= '</table>';

    return $table;
}

echo GetTableResult([
    ['date' => '2017-11-22'],
    ['date' => '2017-11-23'],
]);
```

The point is to store the generated HTML into a variable (`$table`), append strings to it (with `$table .= ...`) and use `${data['field_name']}` inside a string to insert a variable value.

I hope this helps!

Just a general advice: generating complex HTML manually is a painful process. I'd recommend having a look at a templating engine like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) to ease the pain :).

Comment: thanks guy @jeromegamez
Your answer solved the problem!



I'm not using Twig or something similar because the project is really small!

Answer (score 0):

Here, is the solution like I said in my comment. You're missing a bracket and try to echo it out instead of returning.

```
<?php

$arrayData = array(
        array(

        "date" => "1/1/10",

        "name" => "peterparker",
    ),
    array(

        "name" => "Clark Kent",

        "date" => "2/10/27",
    ),
);
function GetTableResult($arrayData) {
  echo "<table id='Grid' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer DTTT_selectable' role='grid' aria-describedby='dynamic-table_info'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Date</th>
              <th class='hidden-480' tabindex='0' aria-controls='dynamic-table' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='teste'>Name</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>";
            foreach($arrayData as $data){
                echo "<tr id='Grid_Linha_1' class='odd' role='row'>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['date']             . "</td>
              <td class = 'hidden-480'>" . $data['name']             . "</td>

            </tr>";
            }

          echo "</tbody>
        </table>";
}

GetTableResult($arrayData);
```

Output:

Date        Name

1/1/10      peterparker

2/10/27     Clark Kent